# Add the name of the input file to a string as the name of the output file in Perl

Tags: perl, output, concatenation

I have loaded my input file using `open`. I want to concatenate the name of the input file with the string 'matched_results', and use that as a name for my output file.

Here is the code I have:

```
use File::Basename;
open(text, "<sampletext7482_ch9.txt");

while (my $line = <text>) {
    push @matches, $1 while $line
        =~ m{
          (###some regex here)
        }xgi;
}


$base = basename $text;
my $filename = "matched_results${base}.txt";
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "$_\n" for @matches;
close $fh;
```

I get the following error.

```
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl/5.18/File/Basename.pm line 341, <text> line 1.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$base = basename $text;
```

`$text` is not defined anywhere.  Therefore, you're passing an `undef` to the `basename` function.

You should have

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

at the top of every program you write to catch problems like that.